# What's wrong in this code? I have difficulty finding out as i just started learning jQuery and jQuery UI

Tags: jquery-ui-dialog

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQuery Dialog Example</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet"     href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    </head>
    <script>
        $(document).ready($(function() {
            //Dialog box 
            $("#dialog").dialog({
                autoOpen: false
            });
            //button to open dialog box
            $("#button").click(function(event) {
                $("#dialog").dialog("open");
            });
        });
    </script>
    <body>
         //div containing info about the dialog box
         <div id="dialog">
         <p>This is supposed to be a calculator</p>
    </div>
    <input id="button" type="submit" value="Open">

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just a friendly tip, you may want to read over this page: [The How-To-Ask Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you can always be sure that your questions are easily answerable and as clear as possible. Be sure to include any efforts you've made to fix the problem you're having, and what happened when you attempted those fixes. Also don't forget to your show code and any error messages!

Comment: i realised my mistake when i was posting another question. thanks for the tip and this mistake would not be made again.

Comment: Don't feel bad. We are a nice community here to help you learn and to help solve your problems. Nobody is mad that you made a mistake. We are all here to help with mistakes! Welcome to the community

Comment: I would recommend changing your title to be somewhat more descriptive. You always want to talk about what's going wrong, not just say that *something* is going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `$(document).ready($(function() {` to `$(document).ready(function() {`
and also check if the braces are properly closed

Comment: Thanks, such a rookie mistake